# problem writing a NSMutableArray to file in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, writefile

A real beginners question.
I have a NSView subclass in which I create a NSMutableArray containing NSValues. When I want to write the array to a file using writetofile:atomatically: the file is created but it contains none of the NSValues that the mutable array does contain.
Does anyone know how I successfully can write this mutable array to a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSValues can't be saved in a plist (which is what writeToFile:atomically: does). Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2) for the values you can save. (NSNumber is a kind of NSValue you can save, but other NSValues will fail.)

If you want to save your array with NSValues, you can use [archiving](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) instead of writeToFile:atomically:. NSArray and NSValue both support archiving, so you just convert the array to an archive and save that data to a file. (It will include the NSValues as well.) The code looks something like this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:@"myPath"];
```

To load it, just use:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"myPath"];
```

Comment: I used NSArchiver and NSUnarchiver instead and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Note that NSKeyed[Un]Archiver is preferred over NS[Un]Archiver nowadays.