# NSMutableArray and saving to a file

Tags: objective-c, save, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class called `Shop` that contains data members (`NSString`, `NSInteger` and `NSMutableArray` that contain another class (that also has `NSString` and `NSInteger`).
Now if I use `NSMutableArray` to hold a list of `Shop`s, what is the best way to save the list to a file and load it later?
Again the class `Shop` contains data members that is another class; both of the classes have `NSString` and `NSInteger` (maybe also `NSData` and `NSDate`).

I heard something about `archiver`??

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem writing a NSMutableArray to file in cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751093/problem-writing-a-nsmutablearray-to-file-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact same as [problem writing a NSMutableArray to file in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751093/problem-writing-a-nsmutablearray-to-file-in-cocoa)

You have non-plist objects in your array and need to use NSArchiver.

Comment: I still didnt understand , does NSArchiver will save all of NSArray list of Shops object to file? (even if Shop have data member like NSArray ) ??
what the difference between NSArchiver to Serializing?

Comment: Did you read this document http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html that was linked to in the dupe's answer?